# How to integrate Python with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, python-3.x, ironpython, python.net

I am making an ASP.NET website in which I would like to use some python 3.x code. Not exactly 'some', but a lot.

I have started searching for a solution but not exactly reached a good one yet. I am using VS 2015, and most of the solutions I found were for VS 2010, 2012. But not for VS 2015.

So I began with installing the PTVS, but that ends up in an error. 
[Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45olI.png)

Please help regarding the installation error and how to set up the integration.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Have you tried pythonnet? Here is presentation with example how to use ASP.NET with Jinja2!

Comment: I forgot to link the presentation: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2016-September/001810.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need exactly python 3 - take a look at IronPython (latest version is 2.7 compatible). For example: [Running IronPython Scripts from a C# 4.0 Program](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2009/10/25/running-ironpython-scripts-from-a-c-4-0-program/).
If you just need to use Python script from your your .NET project - you can just ask python.exe to run the script. Something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = @"\Path\to\python\interpreter\python.exe";
p.Arguments = @"\Path\to\*.py";
p.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.UseShellExecute = true;
Process procScriptExecutor = Process.Start(p);
procScriptExecutor.WaitForExit();
procScriptExecutor.Close();
```